# textarea and submit button same height and same line

Tags: css

I try to make my textarea and submit button within a form to be the same line(and height), so that the text area takes up 90% of the width and the submit button takes 10%, but what I get is the following:

```css
textarea {
display:inline-block;
width:90%;
resize:none;
}
#submit {
display:inline-block;
width:10%;
margin-bottom:-10px
}
```

```html
<form>
<textarea cols="30" rows="1" placeholder="Text here"></textarea>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send"> 
</form>
```

How to fix it so that the button and textarea are the same line, and take up the same height?

Thanks

Comment: form {display: flex; align-items: flex-start}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a combination of the `box-model` and `display: flex`.
Both elements are now on the same line and are the same height, as you asked :)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
 display: flex;
}

textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  resize: none;
}

#submit {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea cols="30" rows="1" placeholder="Text here"></textarea><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

use  `display:flex`

```css
form{
  display:flex
}

textarea {
  display:inline-block;
  width:90%;
  resize:none;
}

#submit {
  display:inline-block;
  width:10%;
  margin-bottom:-10px
}
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea cols="30" rows="1" placeholder="Text here"></textarea>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the border of the elements and also their default margin/padding adds to their size. Therefore they are bigger than 90% or 10%.

A solution would be to either use box-sizing: border-box which prevents margin and padding from adding value to the size or to use a lower percentage like 85% and 8% or something like that.

**Edit**
Read for further information:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can also touch the height of the submit button to make them equal :)

```css
form{
display:flex
}
textarea {
display:inline-block;
width:80%;
resize:none;
}
#submit {
display:inline-block;
width:15%;
height: 21px;
margin-bottom:-10px
}
```

```html
<form>
<textarea cols="30" rows="1" placeholder="Text here"></textarea>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send"> 
</form>
```

Comment: You missed a pixel there. The `height` on #submit should be `22px` for them to have an equal height ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is using `display flex`. Also you can remove `display: inline-block` and `margin-bottom`, and center items with `align-items: center`.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

textarea {
  width: 90%;
  resize: none;
}

#submit {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea cols="30" rows="1" placeholder="Text here"></textarea>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: They don't seem to go on the same line, the submit button is a little bit too low.

Comment: @SirExotic Yes because the button is 18px and textarea is 19px in pristine state. So technically they are aligned vertically, you can put 21px on button and see that the edges bulge equally. It's just that you cannot center subpixel values, i.e. 19px vs 18px.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex;` on the form and remove the `display: inline-block' style from the elements inside

https://jsfiddle.net/zbwv9q97/

```
form{
  display:flex
}

textarea {
  width:90%;
  resize:none;
}

#submit {
  width:10%;
}
```

Comment: Seems like an annoying work-around, plus the textarea and button are not on the same line.

Comment: @SirExotic you're right. sometime I think completely wrong :). edited it with a better working solution but now it's the same as the rest I see haha